# accordion styles arrow wont go down on aria-expanded true

Tags: css, reactjs, accordion

my html looks like this

```
<div class="accordian-wrapper">
<div class="accordion-wrapper__title">
<div aria-expanded=true">
<div class="accordion-wrapper__title__icon-label">
<i class="accordion-wrapper__arrow"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

if aria-expanded is true , i need to move the icon arrow down

what i've tried

```
.accordion-wrapper {
  .accordion-wrapper__title {
    &[aria-expanded="true"]{
      .accordion-wrapper__arrow {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work. what am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your scss file. You are **not selecting the aria-expanded div** in your scss file. Here is the updated code:-

```
.accordion-wrapper {
  .accordion-wrapper__title {
    & > [aria-expanded="true"]{
      .accordion-wrapper__arrow {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**aria-expanded div** is child of **div with class .accordion-wrapper__title**.

Hope it will be helpful.